# Response.End() Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, thread-safety

I have been trying to use the Response.End() method and I keep on getting this error;

```
[System.Threading.ThreadAbortException] = {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}
```

I've googled this and from what I've seen there are 2 solutions, one being to use `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` and the other is to just catch the exception and do nothing.

Firstly the 'catch and do nothing' seems like a very 'bad' way of doing this, surely we should actually handle the exception or do something so that the exception doesn't occur? Surely that's good practice? I don't want my code to be filled with lots of try-catches.

The other method `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` Doesn't seem to be working.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
Response.Write("Blocked IP");
Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
return;
```

All I want to do is to output the text 'Blocked IP' but with using the `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` method the rest of the aspx page gets printed under it like this:

```
Blocked IP

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>

    </title></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="Email.aspx" id="form1">
    <div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZIELtfylTwZMU8vGWe9UrhWClqN3i4rMTvAp8otze+6G" />
    </div>

        <div>

        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intended.  It is designed to throw this exception so asp.net knows to stop the current execution.

From [HttpResponse.End](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```
Calls to the End, Redirect, and Transfer methods throw a ThreadAbortException exception when the current response ends prematurely.
```

It is indended to be used where lets say `Reponse.End()` is called within `Page_Init`, it doesn't let ASP.NET call `Page_Load` and the rest of the events in the page lifecycle.

Comment: Ahh okay, that sort of makes sense. Thanks.